# clarification of int & int inside a if statement in C++

Tags: c++, c

Does the statement return a single bit or concatenation of bits.

```
if(mask[i] & groupbit) {
    //...
}
```

with:

- `i` = an integer
- `mask[i]` = an element of integer pointer
- `groupbit` = An integer

Comment: What is the **exact** data type of your `mask`?

Comment: A statement doesn't return anything. A statement is just a statement.

Comment: Also, integer pointers do not have elements.

Comment: `&` is the `bitwise AND operator`

Comment: I believe "what does bitwise and do?" is the question here.  It returns neither a single bit nor a concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

It will result in an entire integer. When you use the bitwise and, each bit of the two values are and'ed together, and each bit in the result is set accordingly. The result will be the same number of bits as the values being and'ed together.

This is assuming you're using two integer variables.

Comment: I thought so too, but what does it mean to evaluate an integer inside an if statement? I thought if statement evaluate only true/false.

Comment: Any integer that is non zero will evaluate to true. What that means in the context of your code is this : if the two values you are comparing have one or more bits in the same position set, then it will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mask` is a pointer to an integer type the compiler will do the following:

1. Access the `i`-th element of the `mask` "array" as an integer
2. make sure both operands are of the same size (this may involve bit-expansion or truncation)
3. do a bit-wise `AND`
4. if there was a single bit set in the result from the previous `AND` operation the value will be treated as `true`, otherwise as `false`(if every single bit of the result is `0`)